# How to pass touch event frome a UIScrollView's subview to it's superview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, touch-event

I have three views on the window. A UIView contains the UIScrollView,and the UIScrollView contains a UILabel.All these views is 320*460.
Now I want to handle long press event on the UILabel and pass tap event to the UIView. 
I rewrite the lable's touchesEnded: to get the press time.
If the time is short enough, I use [[self nextResponder] touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event] to pass it.
However, even if I rewrite a UIScrollview and add [[self nextResponder] touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event] to it, the UIView can't recive touchesBegan event.
And, if I set userInteractionEnabled=NO for UIScrollView, the UIView get the touchedBegan,and the UILabel can't recive it.

How can I get the touch event in the UILabel first and pass it to the UIView if I need.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.I've achirved my goal by implement a delegate method in my label and achirve it in my UIViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood your question this way.

1. you need long press in UiLabel.
2. you need to detect touch in UIView.

You have scrollview between UIView and UILabel.

1. Add UILongpressGesture in UILabel. (look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer))
2. pass touches from UIscrollview .

Answer (score 0):

Try using the  UITapGestureRecognizer to detect touuch event in UIScrollView

```
  UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self         action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
  [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

and you will get the touches in:

```
  - (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
 { 
   CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:scrollView];
 }
```